# covert 20DEC2007 to yymmdd10 sas

Tags: sas

I want to covert this date format 20DEC2007 to ISO8601 format, please help

i have tried

```
    RFSTDTC= Put(input(TRSTDT,date 11.),yymmdd10.);
```

but I  get error in log as shown below.

```
   error:  Invalid argument to function INPUT
```

Comment: Hi @user10519868, welcome to StackOverflow. It is very beneficial if you have a read of the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guide and provide a code snippet and results of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in your informat name, it should be 'date11.' instead of 'date 11.':

```
data _null_;
    trtStDt = '20DEC2007';
    rfStDtc = put(input(trtStDt, date11.), yymmdd10.);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

use of input with informat date9. read character into date. date format yymmdd10. displays data into ISO8601.

```
data want;
 date1= input("20DEC2007",date9.);
 format date1 yymmdd10.;
;
```